# Importing Module with Python (Head First Python Book)

Tags: python, powershell, python-import

I'm currently following the head-first book on python. Briefly, I am trying to run a python file that imports a module and when I run it I get an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vsearch'`

This is the folder structure:

- New Folder

  - hello_flask.py
  - mymodules.py
  - dist
  - vsearch.egg-info
  - readme.txt
  - setup.py
  - vsearch.py

The following is the code for the relevant (I think):

hello_flask.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from vsearch import search4letters

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello() -> str:
    return 'Hello world from Flask!'

@app.route('/search4')

def do_search()-> str:
    return str(search4letters('life,the universe, and everything', 'eiru!'))
 
app.run()
```

vsearch.py

```py
def search4vowels(phrase: str) -> set:
    """Return any vowels found in a supplied phrase."""
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    return vowels.intersection(set(phrase))
def search4letters(phrase:str, letters:str = 'aeiou') ->set:
    """Return a set of the 'letters' found in 'phrase'."""
    return set(letters).intersection(set(phrase))
```

setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = 'vsearch',
    vesion = '1.0',
    description = 'The Head First Python Search Tools',
    author = 'HF Python 2e',
    author_email = 'hfpy2e@gmail.com',
    url='headfirstlabs.com',
    py_modules = ['vsearch'],
)
```

So the book tells me to run hello_flask.py in windows powershell using `py -3 hello_flask.py` but when I run it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\New folder\hello_flask.py", line 2, in <module>
    from vsearch import search4letters
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vsearch'
```

I have created the distribution file per the book and have searched among the internet as best as I could and I haven't been able to fix it. I have a feeling it would have to be something with the pathway, but I'm not sure. I also tried pip installing vsearch from the powershell which was successful but did not fix my problem. Just in case, the pip install for vsearch installed on c:\users\juan\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (1.1.0).

Comment: Are `hello_flask.py` and `vsearch.py` in the same folder? That isn't obvious from your directory overview.

Comment: yes they are all under New Folder

Comment: You can try `from .vsearch import search4letters`

Comment: I don't know about PowerShell but are you able to run `py -3 -m vsearch` from the same place where you run `py -3 hello_flask.py`?

Comment: What if you remove the space in the folder name?

Comment: @Mortz tried that and now i get ```ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package```

Comment: @JanWilamowski Tried that and is displays ```No module named vsearch```

Comment: @Arseny Tried that with no success, same error

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix! Credits to another page but I had to change the import statement for vsearch on hello_flask.py to `import mymodules.vsearch import search4letters`

Comment: Interesting! What is the content of `mymodules.py`?

Comment: Besides setup.py and vsearch.py, I just have the distribution file info.